# How to exclude a function being affected by main rules in the file?

Tags: php

I've got the following line at the beginning of my profile php file:

```
        if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) || $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == FALSE)
        {
            $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('error_message' => Template::GetLangVar('USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN')));
            return;
        }
.... A LOT OF FUNCTIONS BELOW ...........
```

So, if a non-logged user try to access any of the sub functions, the error will appear.
However, I've added recently a function in this file which requires special treatment.
So, instead of this error message, I should redirect them if they try to access this function in the same profile php file without being affected by the main check if logged in or not. How I can do this to exclude a function from getting affected by this?
BTW: As stated all functions are in the same php script file.

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code, it's really hard to indicate what exactly needs refactoring. If you want to often check or not-check whether the user is logged in, wrap the code for that check in a fitting function/method (ex. `isLoggedIn()`) and return the if-statement its condition.

Then you can edit your code thusly to use `if (isLoggedIn()) {}` and execute different code in different situations.